# How to sort a dataframe with the first occurences of each unique element in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe is

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"necmi": [0, 3, 14, 15, 2, 71, 8, 2, -1],
                   "fehmi": ["trial", "error", "manifest", "trial", "no", "only", "error", "no", "no"]})
```

it is

```
   necmi     fehmi
0      0     trial
1      3     error
2     14  manifest
3     15     trial
4      2        no
5     71      only
6      8     error
7      2        no
8     -1        no
```

So i'd like to sort this df over the `fehmi` over the first occurences of the entries and they are grouped together then. The desired is

```
   necmi     fehmi
0      0     trial
1     15     trial
2      3     error
3      8     error
4     14  manifest
5      2        no
6      2        no
7     -1        no
8     71      only
```

because we saw `trial` first in df so we gather its entries together. Then we saw `error` so they are together and so on.

I attempted with a `groupby` with its `sort` is False as it seemed natural but..

```
df.groupby("fehmi", sort=False)
```

I imagine they are almost in the form I need but it is a "groupby object" and cannot get a form I need, but i tried this to get the groups as is

```
df.groupby("fehmi", sort=False).apply(lambda s: s)
```

but it gives the original df back!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html) + [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

```
df.iloc[np.argsort(df['fehmi'].factorize()[0])]
```

---

```
   necmi     fehmi
0      0     trial
3     15     trial
1      3     error
6      8     error
2     14  manifest
4      2        no
7      2        no
8     -1        no
5     71      only
```

Comment: thank you it is very good! accept when time permits. minor question: do you know what `.apply(lambda s: s)` does after groupby so it returns exactly the same dataframe but not the grouped one?

Comment: here `.apply(lambda s: s)` is practically doing nothing because you are passing in a lambda function that returns the original group itself i.e `s` without applying any transformations to the group.

Comment: i see, i thought it will also order but it puts them back in their original places. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Feho Glad i could help!

Answer (score 2):

Solution with ordered `Categorical` by first values of `fehmi` column, so possible use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['fehmi'] = pd.Categorical(df['fehmi'], ordered=True, categories=df['fehmi'].unique())

df = df.sort_values('fehmi')
print (df)
   necmi     fehmi
0      0     trial
3     15     trial
1      3     error
6      8     error
2     14  manifest
4      2        no
7      2        no
8     -1        no
5     71      only
```

Comment: thank you!! after this dtype is "category". It is kind of string? I looked at the doc but it says "Represent a categorical variable in classic R / S-plus fashion." don't understand :) But i can do `astype(str)` and it is enough to make them strings right?

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but relies on creating indices and rejoining on original df.

```
ordering_df = df.reset_index().groupby("fehmi").first().reset_index()[["fehmi", "index"]]
result_df = df.merge(ordering_df, how="left", on="fehmi").sort_values(["index", "necmi"])[["necmi", "fehmi"]]

necmi   fehmi
0       trial
15      trial
3       error
8       error
14      manifest
-1      no
2       no
2       no
71      only
```